# wrapping TFS continous integration with JBOSS 2.4.11

Tags: ant, build, tfs, jboss, continuous-integration

I am trying to use TFS to auto build and deploy to Jboss server on AIX machine. How do i wrap  the jboss in to a windows service and call it from TFS?

Note: I use ANT to Compile/build my project.

Comment: Which version go TFS?

Comment: we are using TFS 2012

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call out to ANT using the [TFS build extensions](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/45b4e378-5b81-4186-9b7f-21cc5c2f743d). You can call ANT from team build using [these instructions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj155784.aspx#enablebuilds)

Comment: Thank you. Can you also tell how to stop the jboss server.? currently i run a bat/sh file which starts up the server but in order to stop, i just have to kill the process which seems little archaic, how do I wrap the start/stop in to a windows service so that i could just connect it to tfs and run a script and be done with it.

Comment: According to [this](https://community.jboss.org/wiki/StartAndStopTheJBossApplicationServer?_sscc=t) there is a .sh you can in called shutdown.sh [rubik:/tmp/jboss-3.2.3/bin] % ./shutdown.sh -S wrapping it in a windows service seems like overkill. Just call out from ANT or msbuild to the command line